# Find the domain of $A(x) = 1 + \frac{x^3}{2\times3}+\frac{x^6}{2\times3\times5\times6} + \frac{x^9}{2\times3\times5\times6\times8\times9} +\space ...$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series, absolute-convergence

I'm having trouble in finding the domain of the following series:

$$A(x) = 1 + \frac{x^3}{2\times3}+\frac{x^6}{2\times3\times5\times6} + \frac{x^9}{2\times3\times5\times6\times8\times9} +\space  ...$$

I don't see how could I write the denominator for expressing the  $a_n$ term and later apply a the ratio test. Could you please help me find this series domain?

Comment: Try using factorial and sigma notation to make the post cleaner.

Comment: I've miswritten the series. Now it is correct. Thank you for pointing out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that $A_n=\sum_{n \geq 1} a_n x^{3n}$ where $a_0=1$ and:
$$a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n}{(n+2)(n+3)}$$
so by the ratio test as:
$$\frac{x^3}{(n+2)(n+3)} \to 0 \text{  when } n \to \infty$$
for any $x$ the domain is $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Oh my god. I was trying to find a global $a_n$ but did not see that for the ratio test it would be super direct to just leave the recursion